# How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pyqt

Surely this is possible? I have been hunting through PyQt tutorials and documentation but cannot find the answer to it. Probably I just need to phrase my search query differently.

[Edit]

Thanks PEZ for the answer - more details including use of the `.pyw` extension in [Python Programming on Win32 chapter 20](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/index.html?page=2)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you should be able to run your app with pythonw.exe.

Answer (score 17):

An easy way to do this is to give your script a .pyw extension instead of the usual .py.

This has the same effect as PEZ's answer (runs the script using pythonw.exe).

Comment: Ah, you put this in while I was typing. What's the etiquette here, do I delete my answer?

Comment: Neat! I didn't know about the .pyw thingy. +1.

Comment: I think you should leave your answer here - I just wanted to put the link in as it goes into good detail.