# Made a GUI with Pyside, but I still have a cmd window in the back?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, cmd, pyside

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

I made a GUI program using QT Designer and Pyside, and it works completely. The only problem is that whenever I run it, I get a cmd.exe window in the background. This is quite annoying. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310972/getting-rid-of-python-console-in-wxpython-under-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the file extension to .pyw. Double-clicking a .pyw will use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe.

Comment: @cgt This is the better answer. And the recommend thing to do with scripts on windows os.