# How do i hide the console window for my app?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, windows-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

I've made a simple app that opens a QWebView but in addition to the app window Windows console window is opened to.

What could be the reason for this?

```
import sys
import socket
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

class AppWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)        

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 25)  
        self.setWindowTitle('TrayIP')
        self.create_sys_tray()      

        self.hostname = socket.gethostname()
        self.ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.hostname)

        self.label = QLabel("IP: " + self.ip, self)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 14))

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.connect( self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.timerupdate)
        self.timer.start(10000)

    def timerupdate(self):
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.web.load( QUrl('http://xxx') )

    def create_sys_tray(self):
        self.sysTray = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.sysTray.setIcon( QtGui.QIcon('ico.ico') )
        self.sysTray.setVisible(True)
        self.connect(self.sysTray, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)"), self.on_sys_tray_activated)

        self.sysTrayMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        act = self.sysTrayMenu.addAction("FOO")

    def on_sys_tray_activated(self, reason):        
        if self.isVisible ():
            self.setVisible(False)
        else:
            self.setVisible(True)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe

Answer (score 3):

name your file .pyw instead of .py

Answer (score 2):

On default Windows installations, .pyw files are opened without the console window (because they're loaded with pythonw), and .py files load in a console.  So yeah, renaming to .pyw is probably easiest solution.

Also - if you're compiling with py2exe, you'll have to change "console=" to "window="

Comment: This is the best answer. Case in point, I had the issue even though the file extended in .pyw, the reasoning behind the behaviour is what I needed to solve the issue.