# PyQt5 GUI to taskbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a GUI where if you click to a button than it will open a python file. But after the click I want to just see the console. How can I hide the GUI or close without closing the console part?

(Windows 10, Python 3.8.5)

Comment: This question has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872523/how-do-i-hide-the-console-window-for-my-app

Comment: No, because I want the opposite. I want to hide the GUI. (And not always, just if I click to a button).

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. While you can hide the GUI, what is the use of showing the consolle that, at that time, will not be interactive, since the program is still running?

Comment: Because I wanted to build a GUI for my consol python programs. So with buttons, I could reach them. But it will open in the console part of the program. So I wanted to hide the GUI at a point in the program (because it's annoying when I just need the console part of it). Is it still confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    win.show()
    win.setVisible(False)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. Thanks. And another question. It's all good but it could be better if first (when I see the GUI, the console won't pop up. Could I do it somehow? (I know that .pwy won't show the console, but as you know I just want it at the beginning.