# How to get rid of "Command Line" window when running Python script with GUI?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4, windows-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

I am programming under Python2.6 + PyQT + Eric4 environment.
All the GUI and Program parts are done, but here is the problem.
When I run my program, two windows pop up.
One is the window (or frame) I want, the other is like a python interpretor window having a all black undergroud color. And I really don't want this to show.

What can I do to get rid of it?
Please help me out of this.

Comment: which operating system are you targetting ?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using Windows, the only operating system I know to open a prompt when you double click a script. There are two solutions AFAIK: execute the file with the `pythonw.exe` executable, as suggested by @Adrien. If you save the file with the `.pyw` extension, Windows automatically uses `pythonw.exe` for executing the script when you double click

Comment: Thanks a lot！That's so nice of you.

Comment: I didnt understand the answer. do you mean to rename the .exe file to pythonw.exe?

Answer (score 4):

on windows, you can get rid of the console window by using `pythonw.exe` to run your script (instead of the standard `python.exe`)

*(i don't know if there is a similar difference on other operating systems)*

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved. Love this website!

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, the program window only pops up if you save your python file with the extension `.py`  instead of `.pyw`.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this might have been down-voted?

Comment: @Clare - It would have been useful for the downvoters to comment why. But it was probably because this answer got things backwards... ".py" files cause the dos window to open, and ".pyw" don't (per brandizzi's answer)

Comment: @Eli ah yes, good spot - thanks for pointing out the answer is the wrong way round!

Comment: The Python black window still opens up regarding the .pyw extension of the project if it opens a web browser. How do I make the black window not opening from the beginning?