# How to use Python mhmovie without cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a script which combines a `.mp4` and a `.mp3` file using mhmovie. But I can't execute it without showing up the cmd window, even if I use pythonw. I'm using python  3.7.4 and mhmovie 3.2.2. Any ideas on how to disable the cmd window popping up every time?

Here is my code:

```
from mhmovie.code import *

m = movie("video.mp4")
mu = music('audio.mp3')
final = m+mu
final.save("C:\\Users\\Dani\\Music\\output.mp4")
```

Comment: Are you running your script by double-clicking on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of "Command Line" window when running Python script with GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702495/how-to-get-rid-of-command-line-window-when-running-python-script-with-gui)

Comment: You probably can't, because of how mhmovie calls ffpmeg. Try moviepy instead, or look into how mhmovie does it under the hood (not difficult) and emulate that.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes I saved the file as .pyw and then double-clicked on it.

Comment: @andyhasit I don't know what I am doing wrong, but the script with moviepy is only working with python and not with pythonw. If I use pythonw just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I`m fix this error, just do `pip install -U mhmovie`