# How to run wxPython dialog without command prompt window?

Tags: python, windows, dialog, wxpython, windows-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

I have just started to explore wxPython for dialogs, and one thing that I've noticed so far is that every time I start a script (via double click or F5 in IDLE) I get the command prompt window in background, and then wx dialog appears.
Is there any way to remove that command prompt and just get the dialog I've made in wx?

Comment: damnit, just found that renaming _*.py_ to _*.pyw_ does trick.
count this one as closed.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it then

Comment: But how would you make this part of the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved problem : replace extension from **py** to **pyw** and it works without the console in behind.

Comment: It worked, but when I created exe with pyinstaller then it started to show again so I had to add --noconsole.....like this:
$ python pyinstaller.py --noconsole yourprogram.py