# Python terminal window popping up at pygame app run

Tags: python, windows, pygame, windows-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

When I double-click in Windows on my pygame app (.py) the desired pygame window opens, but always along with it, an empty terminal window pops up. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file extension of your file from `.py` to `.pyw`.

See [**Using the Python Interpreter**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts):

> 2.2.2. Executable Python Scripts
>
> The Python installer automatically associates `.py` files with python.exe so that a double-click on a Python file will run it as a script. The extension can also be `.pyw`, in that case, the console window that normally appears is suppressed.