# how to convert python code into executable file

Tags: cmd, executable, python-3.6

I have a python code that run perfect  now i want to convert this code into an **executable file** .I am using python 3.6.

Until now I was able to convert it ,and make it run  but the problem is that when the user try to run the .exe file  **cmd**  window is opened.

how can I make the cmd window to be **hidden** OR to **not show**?

the code below is to create the build folder that includes the converted executable file.

## setup.py

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os
import matplotlib

#os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
#os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\EXECUTABLE_PROGRAMS\\Python3.6\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\EXECUTABLE_PROGRAMS\\Python3.6\\tcl\\tk8.6"


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base='Win32GUI'

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("myPDFviewer.py",base=None)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "this is a test",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["numpy"],}},
    version = "0.01",
    descriptions = "Trying to get this to work",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: How did you convert the python project to an .exe?

Comment: no sir its not a duplicate question.

i installed the cx_Freeze package  and create a setup file   i will edit my question and add the code

Comment: It's still a duplicate, but from an other question (my bad). Read through here:  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650935/cx-freeze-help-is-there-a-way-to-not-make-console-open?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: TLDR: you should define `base=None` as  `base="Win32GUI"`

Comment: thank you this was the issue  convert your comment into an answer to up vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `base=None` to `base="Win32GUI"`