# The exe executable of my application, also opens a console

Tags: python, windows, console, pyqt, exe

I create an exe executable of my application made ​​in pyqt, and everything went well, but when I run the exe in windows before opening the application opens a console and while the application is open that console is also.

I need someone to tell me how to make the console does not come out, or at least not visible.

I've seen some answers to this problem but with C ++ with Python I have not seen anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466203/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-in-a-pyqt-app-running-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is in the post linked to in a comment to your post, but on Windows you can also set a property on a shortcut that starts the app, to have the console minimized. It still shows in taskbar, there id you need it, can be handy in some situations(like during dev to use same script as user will, but not have to bother evrytime start the app to manually minimize the console). In general best to use pythonw.exe or use .pyw extension for your script.