# PyQt: Is there any Time limit widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm creating very simple quiz game, That i want to have delay limit on, so it starts and ends on specific time.

For example there is some function:

```
def Time():
    self.widget1.show()
    self.widget2.hide()

    SomeDelayWidget(60s)(self.SomeFunction)
```

I want this widget to send some kind of signal that activates specific function.

## Sorted:

So is there any delay widget that will time out in specific seconds and after that send signal to some slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timer.

```
tmr = QtCore.QTimer()
tmr.setSingleShot(True)
tmr.timeout.connect(self.SomeFunction)
tmr.start(10000)
```

Comment: Thanks, also is there any way i can print it on label?

Comment: lbl = QtGui.QLabel(); lbl.setText("My Text").

Comment: shellrox this isn't identical but will give you some hints...http://stackoverflow.com/a/36813593/1886357