# I am building desktop app with pyQT need the the application window to pop-up without the cmd window prompt

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am designing a desktop application using python and PyQT in visual studio IDE and my concern is  after the execution of code ,the command prompt window pops-up and later the application window i need to prevent command prompt window from popping up.How do I do this?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

If you set the file's extension to be .pyw and not .py it should run with pythonw.exe and not show a cmd window.

This thread explains it:
[How can I hide the console window in a PyQt app running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466203/10010983)